# iPhone apps crash if debugged on a jailbroken iPhone OS 2.2.1 (libgcc version?)

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, crash, jailbreak

I'm new to iPhone development.
I used a jailbraked iPhone (OS 2.2) for for some time with no problems. Recently I had to upgrade to OS 2.2.1 and after the update I am no longer able to debug apps on the phone. In the console I'm getting the following warning and the apps crash at launch (only when debugged) :

```
...
warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.2.1.sdk/usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
=uuid-mismatch-with-loaded-file,file="/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.2.1.sdk/usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib"
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.2.1.sdk/usr/lib/iPhoneHE.dylib" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.2.1.sdk/usr/lib/libsubstrate.dylib" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.2.1.sdk/usr/lib/HE.dylib" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for "/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib" (file not found).
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

I searched on the web, but was not able to find clear answers. Is this a familiar problem with iPhone OS 2.2.1 on a jailbraked phone? Is there a solution to this?

Many thanks,

Ori

Comment: I wouldn't suggest developing against a jailbreaked/jailbroken (grammar?) phone. It's not the normal scenario/environment that your app will be running under.

Comment: Thanks. 

Don't know about the grammar either. In fact I initially wrote "jailbroken", but it didn't sound cool enough :)

I have no choice but to develop against a jailbroken phone because the iphone is not officially provided in Israel... I believe this is the the situation in other parts of the world too.

Ori

Comment: I'd suggest you get an iPod Touch to develop on then. Don't tell me you need something iPhone specific for your application like GPS? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little late, but it looks like you're having a problem with MobileSubstrate. Just upgrade to the latest version and to OS 3.1.2 and you'll be fine. (You've probably fixed this by now though...)

Comment: I upgraded to 3.x a long time ago and haven't seen this problem anymore either.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old but I thought I would like to pop in and say that jumping into Safe Mode from SBSettings Power option allowed for Debugging on my jailbroken phone.

Comment: This still works for iOS 7.1.2 -- since SBSettings says it doesn't support iOS 7 I needed to download the app "Safe Mode Launcher" from Cydia.